# Is there any PHP (or similar) version of Google Caja that can be practically run from a shared host environment?

Tags: php, javascript, security

I'd love to use [Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) to run user-submitted Javascript 'live demos' in a sandboxed, safe environment, however I see it's Java-based and really have no idea how I'd practically set this up on a shared host (specifically, [MediaTemple's (gs)](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/gs/)). On (gs) I have access to SSH and can install things via command line but it is obviously too limited to support Java etc.

Are there any similar alternatives? My application is PHP (CodeIgniter) based, so a PHP-based solution would be ideal.

Jack

Comment: I just earned the 'Tumbleweed' badge on this question... hooray!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  you can host the sandbox on [Google AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) for free.  This AppEnigne could be a subdomain and then you can have your CodeIgniter application as the main site.